# how to change function signature like clion in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

for example, i have a function declare in test.hpp and definition in test.cpp:

```
float sum(float x, float y)
```

i want to change function:

```
float sum(float x, float y,float z)
```

in clion,we can edit int this window:
[image]

in vscode, i should change function declaration in hpp and than chang functin definition in cpp which is really inconvient.

i have searched,but i only found that only visual studio 2022 support this.

Comment: plus 1 from me, because you're trying to use the right tool for the job

Comment: you can write an extension to do this type of refactoring

Comment: The closest solution is right click on the function name and choose `rename`, but that doesn't work very well

Comment: @rioV8 do you know any extension can do this work?

Comment: **YOU** can add a pull request to the MS C++ extension, it needs a language server and code analyzer to determine if the call to `readParam` is for the correct class or a global or local scope function call, just writing the GUI would be a few (!!) hours work, realizing that the arguments of the function call can be anything, lambda function, initializer lists or arguments to a variadic function, that would not make life easier. Your best alternative is to use the "Go to References" and change the listed calls yourself. What about the format after the refactor, you might get Very long lines

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for reply, i do not think i can finish this kind of work, i just change them by Go to References result.